# Check device input options (mouse and gyroscope)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game that uses the gyroscope and accelerometer as input.

To test it on my PC I created an option to use the mouse as input, however I want to be able to know whether the device has a gyroscope and a mouse so I can change the controls accordingly. This would be extra useful to make my game multiplatform.

How is this possible in Unity3D?

Comment: I am working on a same kind of project. Basically I have to play a game using the gyro and accelerometer sensor. I need your help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Input.gyro.enabled](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-enabled.html) to see if the gyroscope is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

[SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportsGyroscope.html) checks whether the device as gyro or not.

Input.mousePresent checks whether mouse is avialable or not.

To correct the other answer:
Input.gyro.enable is used to enable or disable the usage of gyro.